# Displaying specific text after selecting from two different inputs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 different select fields one with `size` (eg. `10`, `20`, `30`) and the other one with `color` (`red`, `green`, `yellow`). For `size` and `color`, depending on what is selected, I have different prices such as 10, red price is 200EUR, 20 green price is 300EUR etc.

Now I need to know how can I do this with JavaScript so after I've selected the size and color inputs bellow to show me the price.

Can you give me an example of an JavaScript mapping or something like that?

```
 <select id="size" name="size">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
 </select> 

 <select id="color" name="color">
     <option value="red">red</option>
     <option value="green">green</option>
     <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: get selected value for both select and use condition to show the price you wanted

Comment: Not too hard at all. We need to see code first before we know how to incorporate it into what you've already got.

Comment: Can you please add your current HTML and any JS code you've written to the question

Comment: I don't have the javascript code just the select inputs.

Comment: Ok, well anything would help.

Comment: I've edited my post and put the select html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, using an object which holds all values corresponding to color and size

```js
var data = {
  green: {
    10: '100Euro',
    20: '200Euro',
    30: '300Euro'
  },
  red: {
    10: '400Euro',
    20: '500Euro',
    30: '600Euro'
  },
  yellow: {
    10: '150Euro',
    20: '250Euro',
    30: '370Euro'
  }
}
// bind change event handler to listen change event
$('#color,#size').change(function() {
  // getting value from data object based on selected value and updating div text
  $('#res').text(data[$('#color').val()][$('#size').val()]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size">
  <option value=10>10</option>
  <option value=20>20</option>
  <option value=30>30</option>
</select>
<select id="color">
  <option value=red>red</option>
  <option value=green>green</option>
  <option value=yellow>yellow</option>
</select>

<div id=res></div>
```